# How to make server to understand what kind of data was received and vice-versa

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, sockets, flash

I have flash app, it is simple async, nodejs based flash chat.

The situation is: all the data for the server and for the clients is the same, just some text.
My question is: how do I make client to send specific data so server understand's what that data is and runs specific function. And how does client understands what kind of data it gets and what to do with it.

Example: client sends message 'hello' so sever understands that that is just a chat message.
Then client sends 'awesome_btn_cliked' and that is some function should be processed on the server side so the server understand that and send the result data back to the clients.

Client sends: hello = just a message that broadcasted to all clients.
Client 'awesome_btn_clicked': function{1+1=2} -> result broadcasted to all clients.

Something like that. I hope I fully explained what I need.

Comment: Do you have access to the client and server source code? Why not simply create some header scheme where the first two letters of the message indicate the source. For example, "c:hello" the c: could get interpreted by the server as a chat msg. "e:some_btn_click" would get interpreted as an event. The colon is just a sample separator. You could format the message any way you feel. Also, why not use JSON and use attribute values to differentiate the message types?

Comment: Yes I have the access. And I have being thinking about using "e:some_btn_click" style. But could you tell me more about how to use JSON for this? And what could be better for example to develope some simple game alike app?

Comment: Also can I send raw JSON from AS3 to nodejs socket server?

Comment: TY man, you were absolutely right, I would also point your **comment** as the right answer that helped me if only that wasn't a comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send metadata with your data so the server understands what it needs to do. This means you are defining the protocol to which all clients and servers need to support. For these two different cases (either it is a plain chat message or some command the server needs to execute) you can roll your own protocol. But in software development things always start small and grow large (rapidly).

You might want to look into something like XMPP which is a XML based chat message protocol.
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/

Comment: Right now it is just -> **socket.send(msg);** so should it be -> **msg = <meta>+"HELLO WORLD"** ?
I guess XMPP would be too much for me even if it could be the answer.

Comment: msg = "<datatype='chat'>" + "Hello ValRus" + "</datatype>"

Comment: Funny example you are giving with 1+1, on which 2 needs to be sent to all the other clients. Why doesn't your client app that is sending the function just send "2" instead as a chat message?

Comment: omg, TY, that is awesome. Just that simple. Also I guess, I can send the same way JSON string, right?

Comment: That example just what I came up with right away, but the thing is that all the calculations need to be done on the server.

Comment: you could use something simple like JSON, where the properties of the object tell the client/server what to do. E.g. a chat message from the client could be `{'from':PLAYER_ID, 'room':ROOM_ID, 'msg':CHAT_MSG}`. A message from the server could be `{'function_to_call':MY_FUNC}` etc. Depending on your needs, build up your protocol like that - e.g. a message from the server could contain a `type` (`CHAT_MSG`, `CALL_FUNC`, etc). When the client receives it, they check the `type` and react accordingly